# cakephp auth component giving controller not found messages

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a modified AppController.php, logins_controller.php, and a few views

For knownusers I get the following error message: Not sure why, as I'm pointing to the correct controller... Any suggestions?

http://my.ip.address/cakephp/logins/knownusers

```
Authorization adapter &quot;controller&quot; was not found.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace

#0 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php(376): AuthComponent->constructAuthorize()
#1 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php(330): AuthComponent->isAuthorized(Array)
#2 [internal function]: AuthComponent->startup(Object(LoginsController))
#3 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php(103): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(606): ObjectCollection->trigger('startup', Array)
#5 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(104): Controller->startupProcess()
#6 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(89): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(LoginsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#7 /var/www/cakephp/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#8 {main}
```

**AppController.php**

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * This is a placeholder class.
 * Create the same file in app/Controller/AppController.php
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package       Cake.Controller
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/view/957/The-App-Controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array('Auth');

public $helpers = array('Session', 'Html', 'Form', 'Session');

function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'logins', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home');
        $this->Auth->allow('display');
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
        $this->set('Auth',$this->Auth);
}

        function isAuthorized() {
                return true;
        }

}
```

**logins_controller.php**

```
<?php
class LoginsController extends AppController {

        public $name = 'Logins';

        function beforeFilter() {
                // tell Auth not to check authentication when doing the 'register' action
                parent::beforeFilter();
                //$this->Auth->allow('register');
        }

        function register() {
                if (!empty($this->data)){
                        if ($this->Login->save($this->params['data'])) {
                               // $this->flash('Your registration information was accepted. Welcome!','/pages/display/home');
                                $this->Auth->login($this->data);
                                $this->redirect('/pages/display/home');
                        } else {
                                $this->flash('There was a problem with your registration', '/logins/register');
                         }
                 }      

        }

function login() {
                if(!empty($this->data)) {
                        $this->Auth->login($this->data);
                        $this->redirect('/pages/display/home');
                }
        }

        function logout() {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }

} 
?>
```

**login.ctp**

```
<h1>User Login Form</h1>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Login', array('action'=>'login'));
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type'=>'password'));
echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

**knownusers.ctp**

```
<table>
<?php
echo $this->Html->tableHeaders(array_keys($knownusers[0]['Login']));

foreach ($knownusers as $thisuser)
{
        echo $this->Html->tableCells($thisuser['Login']);
}

?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP tries to find the class file according to the argument. eg, 'controller' means it tries to find controllerAuthorize.php. It finds it on Windows, as files are case-insensitive.

On Unix/Linux systems, you should use title case:

```
    'authorize' => array('Controller')
```

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that the issue was using controller authorization.

so I just deleted this line:

```
$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
```

which I believe makes it use basic authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

in the Logins Controller

also 
$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';

should be
$this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');

(although I am talking from the perspective of cake 2.0)